# Extract MIME encoded content from email using JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, mime-message

I have an email message that has `contentType:  TEXT/PLAIN; charset="=?utf-8?B?ICJVVEYtOCI=?="`

What do I need to extractContent to eliminate the `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: =?utf-8?B?ICJVVEYtOCI=?=`

I have tried the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class ExtractContentText
{
    private static String extractContent(MimeMultipart mimeMultipartContent) throws MessagingException
    {
        String msgContentText = null;

        Exception cause = null;

        try
        {
            int numParts = mimeMultipartContent.getCount();

            for (int partNum = 0; msgContentText == null
                    && partNum < numParts; partNum++)
            {
                BodyPart part = mimeMultipartContent.getBodyPart(partNum);
                System.out.println("BodyContent.PartNum: "
                        + partNum + " has contentType:  " + part.getContentType());

                // TODO: Eliminate java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: =?utf-8?B?ICJVVEYtOCI=?=
                Object partContent = part.getContent();
                if (partContent instanceof MimeMultipart)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("Processing inner MimeMultipart");
                        msgContentText = extractContent((MimeMultipart) partContent);
                        System.out.println("Using content found in inner MimeMultipart");
                    }
                    catch (MessagingException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Ignoring failure while trying to extract message content for inner MimeMultipart: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        msgContentText = (String) part.getContent();
                        System.out.println("PartNum: "
                                + partNum + " content [" + msgContentText + "]");
                    }
                    catch (ClassCastException e)
                    {
                        // If it is not a String, ignore the exception and continue looking
                        System.out.println("Ignoring Non-String message content: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MessagingException | IOException e)
        {
            cause = e;
            System.out.println("Failure while trying to extract message content: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Fail if content could not be extracted
            if (msgContentText == null)
            {
                MessagingException ex;
                if (cause == null)
                {
                    ex = new MessagingException("Message content could not be extracted");
                }
                else
                {
                    ex = new MessagingException("Message content could not be extracted - "
                            + cause.getMessage(), cause);
                }
                System.out.println(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        return msgContentText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        Message m = null;
        System.out.println(extractContent((MimeMultipart) m.getContent()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the JavaMail FAQ: [Why do I get the UnsupportedEncodingException when I invoke getContent() on a bodypart that contains text data?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#unsupen)  You can use the [javax.mail.Part.getInputStream()](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getInputStream()) to gain access to the raw bytes and perform your own decoding.

To repair an invalid content type header your can use the [javax.mail.internet.ContentType](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/ContentType.html) to extract the parameter and use the [javax.mail.MimeUtility.decodeText](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText(java.lang.String)) to decode unstructured headers.

```
public static String cleanContentType(MimePart mp, String contentType) {
    String ct = "TEXT/PLAIN; charset=\"=?utf-8?B?ICJVVEYtOCI=?=\"";
    ContentType content = new ContentType(ct);
    System.out.println(content.getBaseType());
    System.out.println(content.getParameter("charset"));
    System.out.println(MimeUtility.decodeText(content.getParameter("charset")));
}
```

In the [javax.mail.internet](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-frame.html) package there are a list of parameters that can be used to change some of the default behaviors.  You can set the system property of `mail.mime.parameters.strict` to `false` to relax some of the rules on content type.  You can also set the `mail.mime.contenttypehandler` to point to fully qualified class name that can fix problems with the content type. The custom class must contain the following method signature:

```
    public static String cleanContentType(MimePart mp, String contentType) {
        try {
            ContentType content = new ContentType(contentType);
            String charset = MimeUtility.decodeText(content.getParameter("charset"));
            charset = charset.replace("\"", "");
            content.setParameter("charset", charset);
            return content.toString();
        } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            return contentType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code cleans the content-type, but I am still not clear on how I would use a "UTF-8" to get the content from my "part" variable.

Comment: Updated the answer.  I was thinking that if you were able to repair that header the getContent might have worked for you.

Comment: And just to be clear, the header you're looking at is bogus and should be reported to the person who sent the message and/or the owner of the program that created the message.  Someone has taken the charset name (UTF-8), put double quote marks around it, put a space in front of it, and then encoded the resulting string with utf-8 before setting it as the value of the charset parameter in the header.  Argh!  It should've just said charset="UTF-8".